# Windows 10 Home upgrade left my PC in infinite restart loop

Tags: windows, memory

my PC completed a scheduled upgrade to Windows 10 from 7. It happened last night and today I am unable to use the PC. It gets to the initial configuration questionnaire and then an Application Error appears:

WerFault.exe - Application Error
The instruction at 0x00007FFEB4F550E referenced memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. The memory could not be read.

The only option I have is to hit OK, then the PC restarts and I get to the same point over again.

Any ideas how to fix this are greatly appreciated. Is there an option to disable error reporting (WerFault)? Safe mode?
Thank you for your time. 
Sam

Comment: You should be able to get Safe Mode to be offered after 3 failed attempts to load Windows.  This sounds like a classic case of a bad driver.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ramhound for your reply!

I found that after stopping the load process, I was able to enter the setup troubleshooting. This means I had to power down the PC during load, and this is important step, because the restart loop did not trigger the emergency troubleshooting mode.  Unfortunately none of the automated fixes solved the issue except the revert to the previous Windows release. Now I have back my data and a healthy Windows 7. 
Thanks Microsoft, the compatibility checks failed miserably! I lost 4 hours to fix the best yet Windows 10.